# Improve SQL query with multiple unions and joins (hdbsql)

Tags: sql, hana

I'd like to improve the following SQL query with regards to performance, I'm a beginner with SQL and working in Hana database, hdbsql.

The task is to grab data into 7 columns that is a pile from 4 tables. I did it with UNION ALL, which as far as I know is very slow.

```
CREATE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, NULL AS column5, tab2.prop2, 'GENERAL' AS STATUS 
    FROM table1 tab1
    INNER JOIN table2 tab2 ON tab1.prop1 = tab2.prop1 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT column1, column2, NULL, NULL, NULL AS column5, tab2.prop2, 'ADD_TERMS' AS STATUS 
    FROM table1 tab1
    INNER JOIN table2 tab2 ON tab1.prop1 = tab2.prop1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tab4.prop2, tab3.prop2, NULL, NULL, tab4.prop1, tab4.prop2, 'NUMBER_TO_TERMS' AS STATUS 
    FROM table3 tab3
    LEFT JOIN table4 tab4 ON tab3.prop1 = tab4.prop1
    INNER JOIN table5 tab5 ON tab4.prop2 = tab5.prop2 
    WHERE tab4.prop2 IS NOT NULL
```

Currently my query results in average of 10 ms. The goal is to reduce it to 5 ms.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, `UNION ALL` isn't slow. It just concatenates the results of different queries. It's `UNION` that's slow, because it removes duplicates. The first two queries return the *same* data though. You could improve performance by removing one of them and returning all the columns.

Comment: 10 ms is pretty fast.